# Single Section within main

Tags: html, header, program-entry-point

Is having a single section within the main tag acceptable or is redundant?

```
<main>
  <section>
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
  </section>
</main>
```

Or should I just put the two section tags within the main... even though all the content within it is relatable.

Also, is having a `<header>` within every single section acceptable? It is classified as “a group of introductory or navigational aids”. But seems like if I were to use it as I've described, it'd be just like using `<h1>-<h6>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<section>` element is used to represent a group of related content. There shouldn't be any issue in nesting these tags. You could also make use of other tags like `<article>`, `<aside>` etc.. The idea behind using these elements is to  give more **semantic meaning to your pages**, allowing computer browser to understand your content better.

There are no restrictions on how to nest them and what tags to use in them. You can have the whole set of html tags with in them (you can use h1-h6, or other elements).

You might want to have a look at these articles:

1. [How to Use The HTML5 Sectioning Elements](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/use-html5-sectioning-elements)
2. http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

Answer (score 0):

1. Question: is the single `section` inside `main` redundant?

   It depends on the semantic meaning of your page. Describe your
   desired page layout in natural language. If you say *"the main area
   has a section that contains many sub-sections"*, then your HTML is
   right on the money. If you say *"the main area is broken down into a
   few sections"*, then your single `section` sounds like an evolved form
   of the div-itis virus - the one that left a lot trash behind: wrappers,
   containers, container-wrappers, content-wrappers, main-content-wrappers,
   wrapping-containers, containing-wrappers...
2. Question: is `header` within every section acceptable?

   Yes. But again, do the above natural language litmus test to
   determine if it is suitable.

   There's also some confusion between `<h1>-<h6>` vs `<header>`. Think of `header` as an "introductory part" within a section. It may or may not be necessary in your markup. If your introductory part of the section consists of, say, only a `<h1>`, you should probably omit use of the `<header>`; but if your introductory part includes a few items, e.g. a heading, a logo, a nav bar, then it's probably a good idea to wrap them in a `<header>` tag.